# How do I vertically align text within a td and a span?

Tags: html, html-table, valign

Here is what I have, the only CSS is styling for my  tags, so there is no relevant CSS effecting this.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><span style="font-size:20px; color:#ed8f49">Fall Classes with</span><img src="REDACTED.png" height="90" width="482"></td>
</tr>
```

When I have only the TD things work fine, but as soon as I put that text in a span or try to make it h1 it aligns to the bottom, even if I add alignment attributes to the span as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `align="top"` or `style="vertical-align:top` on your image :)

Comment: the issue is that the image has about 50pixels of transparency at the bottom, I am sourcing the picture from the page of the company who I am preparing the email for and I do not have access to their ftp to host a different image.  If the text aligns to the top while the image stays where it is (aligned to the top) then the text on the image should line up with the text off the image.  but this seems to be impossible...

Comment: you can fiddle with it a little by specifying line-height for the text, to get it perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top;">
```

The attribute `valign` is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: I tried that first, and even without the span and h1 this did not work, hence why I broke out the deprecated tag.  This is for a simple newsletter that will be sent out once to 50 people, I'm not superconcerned about how hackish the code is.  thanks for the suggestion tho